# CMAKE: how to include and link alternative libraries?

Tags: boost, sqlite, cmake

My project need four libraries including `MPI`, `BOOST`, `VTK` and `SQLITE3`. Since `BOOST` and `SQLITE3` are too old, I installed new version of the two libraries and the old version are not uninstalled:

```
BOOST    # alternative BOOST
  |___include
  |___lib
  |
SQLITE   # alternative SQLITE
  |___bin
  |___include
  |___lib
  |___share
  |
Mypoject
  |___src
  |    |___CMakeLists
  |    |___.cpp and .h file
  |
  |___CMakeLists
```

And I used `FindSQLite3.cmake` to find the alternative SQLite3:

```
# Look for the header file.
FIND_PATH(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR sqlite3.h /export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include)

# Look for the library.
FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY sqlite3 /export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib)

# Handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set SQLITE3_FOUND to TRUE if all listed variables are TRUE.
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SQLITE3 DEFAULT_MSG SQLITE3_LIBRARY SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)

# Copy the results to the output variables.
IF(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    SET(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY})
    SET(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR})
ELSE(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    SET(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)
    SET(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
ENDIF(SQLITE3_FOUND)

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)
```

I am trying to link alternative libraries by following lines:

```
# CMake version
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.6)

SET(VERSION 0.1)
SET(SOVERSION 1)

# searching ENV{PATH} to find mpicc and
# store the path of mpicc to MPI_INTEL_C
FIND_PATH(MPI_INTEL_C mpicc $ENV{PATH})

# searching ENV{PATH} to find mpicxx and
# store the path of mpicc to MPI_INTEL_CXX
FIND_PATH(MPI_INTEL_CXX mpicxx $ENV{PATH})

IF(MPI_INTEL_C AND MPI_INTEL_CXX)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Intel MPI compiler is used.")

    # set C++ complier as mpicxx, and set C complier as mpicc   
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)
    SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
ENDIF(MPI_INTEL_C AND MPI_INTEL_CXX)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
IF(VTK_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "VTK IS USED")
    include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
ELSE()
    MESSAGE("VTK IS NOT FOUND")
ENDIF(VTK_FOUND)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/iRoot-make/cmake")


FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3 REQUIRED)
MESSAGE(STATUS "${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "${SQLITE3_LIBRARY}")

# try to link boost--error
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/export/home/hh/hh/boost/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/export/home/hh/hh/boost/lib)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
IF(MPI_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "MPI IS USED")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
ELSE()
    MESSAGE("MPI IS NOT FOUND")
ENDIF(MPI_FOUND)

aux_source_directory(. DIR_SRCS)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${DIR_SRCS})

#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(iRoot)

# set location of binary generated by the program, 
# here PROJECT_BINARY_DIR = DIR OF build
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# set location of lib generated by the program
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

install(TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)
```

CMake could not find the alternative `SQLite3`, and could find the old version:

```
-- /usr/include
-- /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so
```

but the new version is located at:

```
/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include
/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.so
```

I am very new to `CMAKE`, please help me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain this using boost as an example. This is how I have it done in my setup.

Let's assume the newer boost version is installed in:

```
/export/home/hh/hh/Boost/boost-1_60/boost/include/
/export/home/hh/hh/Boost/lib
```

Now in `CMakeLists.txt` add these paths to `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
LIST (APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/Boost/boost-1_60")
LIST (APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/Boost/lib)
```

Then call `FindPackage` mentioning the minimum required version and optionally the required library components which are built into .so:

```
FIND_PACKAGE (Boost 1.60 COMPONENTS "program_options" "log" "system" "filesystem" "thread" "python" REQUIRED)
```

This should work similarly for other libraries too.

---

**Update:**
Add to `CMakeLists.txt` paths to your custom cmake modules, for example the path where `FindSQLite3.cmake` is located:

```
LIST (APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${MAINFOLDER}/tools/share/cmake")
```

Then call: `FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3 REQUIRED)`

Also remove: `/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include` and `/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib` from `FindSQLite3.cmake` but have them added in a similar to boost way.

Comment: Thank you fro your reply. Your solution succeed  in finding `boost`, but it fail on finding `sqlite`. `Could not find module FindSQLite.cmake or a configuration file for package SQLite.`

Comment: Hi @doqtor, in FindSQLite3.cmake, I made these modifications: `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/export/home/hha/hh/iRoot-make/cmake")`,
`FIND_PATH(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR sqlite3.h)`,
`FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY sqlite3)`; and in CMakeLists.txt, I add these two lines: `LIST(APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include")`,
`LIST(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib")`. But the error just like before.

Comment: @just_rookie I wasn't very clear, sorry, keep `FindSQLite3.cmake` unmodified like [this](https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite3/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake) and make changes to your `CMakeLists.txt` only. I edited my answer, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your solution is clear to me. Followed your comments, I added three lines to my `CMakeLists.txt` before `FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3 REQUIRED)`: `LIST(APPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/include")`, 
`LIST(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/sqlite/lib")`, 
`LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/export/home/hh/hh/iRoot-make/cmake")`. But cmake still could find the old version, but not the new version.

Comment: Try to specify the minimum required version number like in boost or uninstall the old version.

Comment: `But cmake still could find the old version, but not the new version.` - Does CMake finds old versions **both** for `SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `SQLITE3_LIBRARIES`? Or one of them refers to new version, but another to old one? E.g., this script [FindSQLite3.cmake](https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite3/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake) searches include file `sqlite3.h`, but library `sqlite` (without version suffix).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Both `SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `SQLITE3_LIBRARIES` were found for old version.

Comment: I think the old one is found because the path to old one is before the new one on the path list. Apart from specifying the version name or uninstalling as I mentioned in my previous comment you could try to make the path to the new one first in `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` lists. Actually check first if path to the old one appears on that lists.

Comment: @doqtor `FIND_PACKAGE(SQLite3 3.11 REQUIRED)` have no effect on the result, still find the old version. Could we delete or path of the old version from the path list?

Comment: @doqtor This [FindSQLite3.cmake](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake) is the right answer.

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` should be sufficient for finding header files there: directories in this variable are searched **before others** (see precise algorithm description for [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_path.html)). Until you actually have no required file there, or forget to clear cache before re-running cmake (entry found by `find_path` is cached, and cached value is never changed by `find_path` itself).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding these settings in the CMakeLists.txt you should change appropriate value in the cache (builddir/CMakeCache.txt). You can do this

- manually
- with `cmake -D VARNAME=value .`
- with cmake GUI app

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you explain your answer in detail?